# Redirection failure in django

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls

I'm trying to create a dashboard on Django
It consists of 7 pages and every third page is giving error
PYCHARM, django module
Localhost
Python 3,7
Django Latest version

I have written  all the URLs properly And it comes like that

Localhost/maps

this one is fine but the next click is

Localhost/maps/reports

now this is error

I want that every time a link is clicked  it goes back to localhost and then take the new link.The codes urls are like this

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('login/', views.login),
    path('maps/', views.maps),
    path('profile/', views.profile),
    path('preferences/', views.preferences),
    path('register/', views.register),
    path('reports/', views.reports),
    path('weather/', views.weather),
    path('help/', views.help),
]
```

Comment: Edit your post and add full error traceback.

Comment: `localhost/maps/reports` should be handled by `views.maps` so please add content of `views.maps`. And full traceback too, as comment above says. Thanks.